# Difference between Feature licenses and Permission set licenses

Tags: licenses, userlicense

I am trying to understand the difference between **Feature Licenses** and **Permission Set Licenses**.

From the documentation, it seems both licenses entitles user to access an additional feature that is not included with their user license. If that is true, I was wondering why salesforce has to come up with two versions? Why can't it just be feature license or Permission Set License?

Would appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the surface, you're correct and both extend the access a user has to the platform. But they do it in different ways.

A feature license just grants a user access to a specific feature. You either enable it or disable it in the user's profile and that's it.

Permission set licenses grant more granular control because the user needs both a **permission set license** giving them the right to use a feature or certain features and a **permission set** describing what they can do with it.

There's validation involved when assigning the permission set to  user. So if I create a **permission set** with permissions that requires a specific **permission set license** I cannot assign the **permission set** to a user unless they also have the related **permission set license**.