# Licenses: What Permission Set & Feature Licenses go with what User Licenses?

Tags: permissions, licenses, user-management, feature-management

IIUC, the purposes of my org's User Licenses are:

- Community: log in to Community, aka Site, aka Experience Cloud?
- Identity: also log in to Community, but different somehow? (unused)
- Salesforce: log in to SFDC/SFDX with full features & permissions (or less, depending on their Profile).
- Chatter: log in to Chatter, which is deprecated.

We also have a bunch of Permission Set Licenses & Feature Licenses (mostly unused) such as Analytics, CRM, Einstein, Sales Cloud, Sales Console, Knowledge, Marketing, Service Cloud, etc. **What User License(s) do they work with?**

AFAICT, Salesforce User licenses already include access to those things without needing PSL & FL (but we don't use several of them, so maybe I'm wrong about that).

(Background: I've been told to configure users to log in to a limited subset of SFDC via CRM-User PSL. What User License is that?)

These related questions are similar but don't name names specifically:

- [Difference between Feature licenses and Permission set licenses](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162887/difference-between-feature-licenses-and-permission-set-licenses)
- [User licenses and Permission Set Licenses](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/172755/user-licenses-and-permission-set-licenses)
- [Difference between service user permission set licenses & feature licence](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164017/difference-between-service-user-permission-set-licenses-feature-licence)

Comment: _I've been told to configure users to log in to a limited subset of SFDC via CRM-User PSL_. This should be your question - see [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @identigral thanks I thought about that, but I want to understand the relationship between PSL/FL & UL/Profile in general, not just in this one case.

Comment: Take a look at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/salesforce-licensing and https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162887/difference-between-feature-licenses-and-permission-set-licenses